# How to create custom map view in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to create an original map type (view) for my application (e.g. Ingress game has its original black map view with only roads etc.). Currently on my project I'm using Google Maps v2, but if it is possible to create new map view other way, it would be great.

I was searching a lot over the internet on how to create a custom map view in Android and wondering that results are not as expected. Mostly all of them are talking about inserting tiles over the standard map (either NORMAL, HYBRID etc.), but do I have to create a tile for a whole world map?

Comment: Have you checked http://www.mapbox.com ?

Comment: Wow! I haven't seen it and google did not put it in results :( thanks a lot, that's a great SaaS.

Answer (score 1):

Within Android, it is not possible to create a custom-styled map view at the moment. See https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5463 for the bug reported against the Maps team.

Ingress can do this because it's made by Google, so they have access to private code to enable this feature.

**Note:** If you do want to follow the bug, please just hit the star in the top left near the issue number rather than commenting, please!

Answer (score -1):

You can create custom JSON entries for Google Maps to color code the map how you see fit, look into that.  http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is only possible for maps embedded in a website, not within an Android application.